# Referencing incomplete class types - C++

Tags: c++

Imagine a hypothetical scenario as this.

I've created two classes `Boolean` and `String` which are both independent of each other (including their respective methods & properties).

And I require one these classes (`Boolean`) to create a new `String` when a certain method in it is called (let's say `toString`) and the other (`String`) to create a new `Boolean` when a method in it (`isEmpty`) is invoked.

Here's the code:

**SOURCE CODE 1**

```
#include <string.h>

class Boolean;
class String;

class Boolean {
    bool value = false;
    public:
        Boolean(bool value) { this -> value = value; }
        String toString() { return String(value ? "true" : "false"); }
};

class String {
    char* value;
    public:
        String(const char* value) { this -> value = strdup(value); }
        Boolean isEmpty() { return Boolean(!strcmp(value, "")); }
};
```

Of course, this doesn't work because in the `Boolean` class' `toString` method, the compiler complains that the `String` class it's using to construct a new object is of an incomplete type.

The farthest I've been able to get with this so far has been the code below (which I know is accurate):

**SOURCE CODE 2**

```
class Boolean;
class String;

class Boolean {
    bool value = false;
    public:
        String* toString() {
            String* string;
            return string;
        }
};

class String {
    char* value;
    public:
        Boolean* isEmpty() {
            Boolean* boolean;
            return boolean;
        }
};
```

But of course, if I run this code from a compiled C++ file, it I print the string value of a `Boolean` object using `Boolean.toString`, it will return something arbitrary and inaccurate.

How does the concept in the first source code script translate to functioning C++ code?

Thanks for reading through (and helping out).

Comment: Mutual dependency is a code smell. You should design your classes that it doesnt happen in first place. However, to suggest how to resolve it we would need to know what is your actual case (not just some hypothetical example).

Comment: @user463035818 That might be true in some cases, but this example seems fragrant to me, and I'll bet there's similar relationships in the standard library.

Comment: @Barmar yes, sometimes there is no way around. I think the answer given is a good one and nicely demonstrates how strongly the implementations are coupled (have to define stuff in the right order) only because the two are using each other

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're close, but at the time that you're making the class implementation for `Boolean`, the only thing it knows is that there will be a class named `String` at some point. It doesn't know anything about `String`'s constructors, so you can't call them yet!

Instead, you can declare the class names, implement the classes while only declaring their functions, and then actually implement the functions *after* both classes and their functions have been fully declared.

This would look like:

```
class String; //We need to know there will be a class String for Boolean declaration

class Boolean {
    bool value = false;
    public:
        Boolean(bool value) { this -> value = value; }
        //We can't implement this yet since it requires 
        // calling String functions which haven't been declared yet
        String toString(); 
};

class String {
    char* value;
    public:
        String(const char* value) { this -> value = strdup(value); }
        //This is fine to implement since Boolean is already fully declared
        Boolean isEmpty() { return Boolean(!strcmp(value, "")); }
};

//String has been declared, now we can implement this function
String Boolean::toString() { return String(value ? "true" : "false"); }
```

See it work here: [ideone](https://ideone.com/xL5cao)

---

The reason your pointer example works is because the pointers aren't calling any constructors. The only thing you need to know to make a pointer is that a class exists. If you'd tried to use the `new` operator, you probably would've run into the same issue since at that point you couldn't know which constructors the `String` class will have.